# Kendo UI for MVC4 MultiSelect Widget Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been using Kendo UI in my asp.net MVC4 project, and it works normally.

I have used widgets like `DropDownList, Grid,` and it has no problem.

Recenetly I would like to change some of my `DropDownList` to `MultiSelect`,

so I try to copy the example in this link: [MultiSelect Basic Usage](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/serverfiltering)

However, an error message is shown:

`CS1061: 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<XXX>' does not contain a definition for 'MultiSelect' and no extension method 'MultiSelect' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<XXX>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`   XXX is the model passed into that View.

I have google it and it seems like a problem about the namespace / reference config, yet as I said, I have used other Kendo UI widget normally...

Below is my code of my WORKING `DropDownList`, and a not working `MultiSelect`

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
       .Name("vendorName") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
       .DataValueField("VendorCategoryID") // The value of the dropdown is taken from the EmployeeID property
       .DataTextField("VendorName") // The text of the items is taken from the EmployeeName property
       .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetVendors", "GenReport"); //Set the Action and Controller name
                });

            })
            .OptionLabel("---Please Select---")
            .Events(e =>
                {
                    e.Change("vendorOnChange");
                })
)

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("required")
      .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
      .BindTo(new List<string>() {
          "Steven White",
          "Nancy King",
          "Anne King",
          "Nancy Davolio",
          "Robert Davolio",
          "Michael Leverling",
          "Andrew Callahan",
          "Michael Suyama",
          "Anne King",
          "Laura Peacock",
          "Robert Fuller",
          "Janet White",
          "Nancy Leverling",
          "Robert Buchanan",
          "Andrew Fuller",
          "Anne Davolio",
          "Andrew Suyama",
          "Nige Buchanan",
          "Laura Fuller"
      })
      .Value(new string[] { "Anne King", "Andrew Fuller" })
)
```

Here is the Intellisense of my VS2012, no MultiSelect...
[image]

Can anyone help me out and tell me how can I use the `MultiSelect`?  Thanks!

Comment: which version of kendo UI you are using?

Comment: I can't find back the installer...yet the folder containing the Kendo UI is named "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q3 2012",  and I am using the dll of "Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q3 2012/wrappers/aspnetmvc/Binaries/Mvc3/Kendo.Mvc.dll"  Does it sounds like a Kendo UI version problem? If yes, I can tell my boss then I may use other workaround to solve it instead...Thanks!

Comment: Multiselect was added in Q1 2013 release of Kendo. http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui-web/release-history for all major version releases. If you still have an active Telerik subscription then either install from the account page or from the Telerik launcher.

Comment: Thanks..it actually saves my day!

Comment: @DavidShorthose Add it as the answer. :)

Comment: instantly accepted ;)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested here is the answer from my comment:

Multiselect was added in Q1 2013 release of Kendo. [Telerik Release RoadMap](http://telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui-web/release-history) for all major version releases. If you still have an active Telerik subscription then either install from the account page or from the Telerik launcher.